# How to programmatically convert a loop to a single expression?

Tags: c#, linear-algebra

I have been reading a book about mathematics for linear algebra and calculus for programming, and one thing that has stuck out to me is the verbosity of the code.  First of all, I know what it is that way, the performance is much better than using a for-loop, but, this makes the code extremely hard to read.

Is there a way to use a for-loop to create the verbose function, that way, the code is more maintainable?

Here is a very simple example of what I am talking about:

```
public int Sum(int[] a, int[] b, int size)
{
   var sum = 0;

   for(var index = 0; index < size; index++)
   {
      sum += a[index] + b[index];
   }

   return sum;
}
```

Now let's say `size` is 3.  Is it possible to produce a single expression from the method `Sum` that looks like:

```
public int Sum3(int[] a, int[] b)
{
   return a[0] + b [0] + a[1] + b[1] + a[2] + b[2];
}
```

So, in actuality, the method `Sum` is not execute to do the summation, instead, it is used to create a `delegate` which can do the summation.  It would end up looking like `Func<int[], int[], int> Sum3`.

The goal would be to use this approach to do operations like the dot product, determinant and matrix multiplication.

**UPDATE**:

I am NOT looking to sum two arrays in one line of code. That was simply an example. I want to be able to do any vector or matrix operation without actually looping.

Comment: What you're probably looking for is a **map** function.

Comment: What does "problematically" mean in your title?

Comment: If you are trying to figure out a formula, its not going to be in C# that will help you

Comment: @Blorgbeard I want to be able to take a template function like `Sum` and create a function during run-time that always produces the same result as the template function, but does not use any loops.

Comment: Ah, "programmatically", right?

Comment: Oh goodness gracious, why did autocorrect change programmatically to problematically.

Comment: If I were you, I'd just write the clear version of the code, with loops intact. Worry about unrolling or other optimizations if and when you hit a performance issue.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @DanByström A simpler alternative to directly generating IL, might be to construct an expression tree and compile it into an invokable delegate. Except that the C# compiler cannot convert `for` loops into expression trees.

Comment: Generating IL is FUN! :-)

Comment: @ZevSpitz Can you chain expressions together? I know in an AST, you can have expressions that are either (e, e) or (e), so the first n-1 elements would be (e,e) and the last would be (e).  I like the idea of not generating the IL code from scratch, since that would mitigate part of the reason for doing this, i.e. readability and maintainability.

Comment: I have yet to encounter a for loop that is hard to read... Especially if the programmer puts a comment or 2. I'd say it should be more natural for a programmer to be cable of easily grasping a for loop than searching for ways to eliminate them. If it's a question of keeping the performance but reducing the "verbosity", you could probably make a preprocessor to somehow shorten the for loop syntax.

Comment: @ZevSpitz you don't need for loops you just chain expressions properly. It is possible to express the code  for `Sum3` method with expressions.

Comment: @Artur I am not looking to simplify a for-loop.  Because a loop has a jump statement, it will be slower than the verbose implementation.  That is what is hard to read, but I would like to use a loop and get similar performance by converting it behind the scenes.

Comment: @Eldar do you have an example of this? Also, would it be possible for more complicated tasks like finding the determinant of an nxn matrix?

Comment: @DanByström is it possible to modify the IL code of `Sum` so it becomes `Sum3`?  I really do not want to have to write IL code from scratch if I can avoid it.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam No, I don't think so. But it is easy to do. I once wrote an expression evaluator, which took an arbitrary string, like "3+4*x" and converted it to IL. Wasn't hard at all.

Comment: @DanByström do you have any good resources that can get me started?  I have not actually done IL code generation, I just know of it.

Comment: Sorry, cannot remember, just google it. But I had absolutely no experience before either. It didn't take many hours to work it all out, really. Good luck and have fun! :-)

Comment: @Eldar My understanding is the OP wants to 1) take an already written and compiled function like `Sum` and 2) transform it somehow into `Sum3`. 2 can be done with expression trees; but In order to do 1, it's necessary to read the IL and parse it, in order to be able to produce a corresponding expression tree.

Comment: @ZevSpitz that just about sums it up.  Either that, or doing it with something like `Expression.Lambda`.  I don't want to have to make more code for `Sum4` through `SumN`.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam I've described the second half in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59473382/111794), but as I said, I don't know how to write a program that parses existing IL.

Comment: I've rolled back invalid edit you've made to the question  - if you have an answer post  it as an answer. It is not allowed on SO to convert valid question into invalid one by combining question and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is only a partial answer; it doesn't deal with reading the IL of the `Sum` metbod.)

Once you've parsed the original function (`Sum` in this case), you can construct the corresponding `Sum3` function as follows:

```
// using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;

var a = Parameter(typeof(int[]));
var b = Parameter(typeof(int[]));
var expr1 = Lambda(
    Add(
        Add(
            Add(
                Add(
                    Add(
                        ArrayIndex(a, Constant(0)),
                        ArrayIndex(b, Constant(0))
                    ),
                    ArrayIndex(a,Constant(1))
                ),
                ArrayIndex(b, Constant(1))
            ),
            ArrayIndex(a, Constant(2))
        ),
        ArrayIndex(b, Constant(2))
    ),
    a,
    b
);
var fn = expr1.Compile();
fn.DynamicInvoke(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5, 6 });
```

Of course, you will probably want to customize the logic based on what is in the IL.

Also note that this may well be less performant, because the time it takes to compile expression trees is usually at least an order of magnitude greater than simply looping. Unless you can cache the compiled delegates for various values of `size`, and the number of usages justifies this.

---

NB Most of this code comes from the [ExpressionTreeToString library](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString) that I've written, which can produce the factory method calls needed to create the given expression tree.

```
// using ExpressionTreeToString;

Expression<Func<int[], int[], int>> expr = (a, b) => a[0] + b[0] + a[1] + b[1] + a[2] + b[2];
Console.WriteLine(expr.ToString("Factory methods"));
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed!  I am not going to parse the IL code, that seems crazy when you can just do an expression tree like you did.  I did some testing, and the component-wise vector addition method done with the expression tree is actually 80% faster.  This way, I can have the loops for making the expression tree, but the actual execution at run-time will have no loops.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam I was assuming you'd start from an existing function like `Sum`, parse the IL of that function, and create an expression tree based on the logic. But if you're not parsing the IL of `Sum`, how will you know which expression tree to build?

Comment: Instead of starting with `Sum` and converting it, I just am going to have `Sum` make the tree.  I will update the post to show what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way is applicable to you:

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] arr2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

int index = 3;
var overallSum = arr1.Take(index).Sum() + arr2.Take(index).Sum();
```

Comment: I don't think that would work for what I am trying to do.  I am not looking to convert the code to just a single line, I want the execution to be a single expression.  I believe using LINQ expressions still iterates over the data.  I want to remove the iteration.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam What's the difference between manual writing `a[0] + b [0] + a[1] + b[1] + a[2] + b[2` and `array.Take(index).Sum()`?

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam - There is a big difference between "1 expression" and no iterations. Please state very clear what the requirements are

Comment: @StepUp when that compiles down to the IL code, the straight addition will be just that, addition.  The loop will have jump statements, making it slower.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want no iteration over the data in your final runtime, I do not believe it to be possible to accomplish this during the compile time, unless you always know the exact length of your arrays (or you make `Int32.MaxValue` overrides for your `sum`). You'd have to write some script with your C# code during the runtime and then execute it.